# Where to store in-memory app info - Angular

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular2-nativescript

In my Angular app I want to store a whole bunch of data for my user, in memory, **to be used in many places throughout the application** (so that I don't have to make extra calls to the server).

Examples of what I have to store:

- User's personal info (I have a User class)
- Alerts list (I have an Alert class)
- Latest Activities list (I have an Activity class)
- User's Pet list - includes a bunch of info about each pet (I have a Pet
  class)

The data retrieval for these is happening in different services, such as sign-in.service.ts, pet.service.ts, etc.

I'm thinking to hold all this info in a service or services.

Is it "best practice" to store this information in one service with a function to get and to set each thing, or to have a separate service for each thing on my list?

EX: Should I have 1 "app-state.service.ts" or should I have "user-personal-info.service.ts", "alerts.service.ts", "activities.service.ts", and "pets.service.ts"?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is this data is supposed to be stored even after closing browser?

Comment: @Szarik - no, it's not supposed to be stored after closing the browser.

Comment: So, if you are not going to do on this data many operations, one service should be enough (just to store and override existing data), it won't make mess in code with `n` service calls. It will be clean and easy to use it accross whole app.

Comment: @Szarik I anyhow have a data retrieval service for each of the items, so perhaps those same services should store the data? Or should data storage services be separate?

Comment: Huh, that actually depends how big your application can be and it's structure. Consider this if you have `module A, module B...` and in `module A` you are retrieving `user personal data` and in `module B ` you are retrieving `activies` it's should be seperate `services` that will send retrieved data to `shared service` and then every call to get data should be adressed to that `shared service` which holds `activities, user personals, pets etc.`, however if it will be one-module small app then just one service that will retrieve and distribute data through components should be enough.

Comment: let me know if you find this useful :)

Comment: @Szarik - thanks for the input here.